# Tensorflow 2.14.0 (with CUDA) not registering CUDA?

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow2.0, nvidia

I'm trying to use Tensorflow with my GPU. My system is Fedora Linux 38, NVIDIA drivers 535.113.01 (currently latest) working as expected on my system.

I created a Python environment with Python 3.9 (AFAIK version 3.11 won't work to install TF 2.14.0 using pip).

On the activated environment I install TF as follows:

```
python3.9 -m pip install tensorflow[and-cuda]
```

I can see that pip installs Tensorflow and many required libraries (cublas, cuda, cull and others).

All seems ok but then when I import tensorflow I get this error:

`>>> import tensorflow as tf`
`2023-10-22 01:58:31.798579: E tensorflow/compiler/xla/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_dnn.cc:9342] Unable to register cuDNN factory: Attempting to register factory for plugin cuDNN when one has already been registered`
`2023-10-22 01:58:31.798611: E tensorflow/compiler/xla/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_fft.cc:609] Unable to register cuFFT factory: Attempting to register factory for plugin cuFFT when one has already been registered`
`2023-10-22 01:58:31.798638: E tensorflow/compiler/xla/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_blas.cc:1518] Unable to register cuBLAS factory: Attempting to register factory for plugin cuBLAS when one has already been registered`
`2023-10-22 01:58:31.804107: I tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:182] This TensorFlow binary is optimized to use available CPU instructions in performance-critical operations. To enable the following instructions: AVX2 FMA, in other operations, rebuild TensorFlow with the appropriate compiler flags.`

I then used the docker image from Tensorflow:  tensorflow/tensorflow:latest-gpu, as a last option, but this showed exactly the same error

Other information

- Python version: version should be >=3.9 and < 3.11 (I tried with many versions in between)
- No local installation of CUDA/CUdNN: I deleted CUDA & CUdNN, used "find / -iname cuda" to make sure there is no trace
- I did reinstalled the drivers and tried version 520 too, same problem

I'm trying to figure out what is going on, when Tensorflow says "...one has already been registered 2023-10-22" for cuDNN, cuBLAS, cuFFT to be able to understand at leat what to look for but I can't find anything useful on the web.

Comment: related?: https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/62075

Answer (score 9):

After 72hs of trial and error with no luck, including reinstalling various versions of the nvidia driver, I reinstalled the operating system and followed the process:

- Install drivers (no cuda!)
- Create python env
- Install tensorflow[and-cuda] (using Python 3.9

Now the importing Tensorflow, although it shows the same warning, will use the GPU:

```
physical_devices = tf.config.experimental.list_physical_devices('GPU')
if len(physical_devices) > 0:
    print("We got a GPU")
    tf.config.experimental.set_memory_growth(physical_devices[0], True)
else:
    print("Sorry, no GPU for you...")
```

This shows that I finally have my GPU up and running... now I can go and have another 72hs of wrestling with data...

Comment: Did you figure out why the warnings are shown and how we can get rid of it?

Answer (score 0):

1. I have the no error message in my local machine with jupyter notebook.
2. When I used colab (I use free charge account), I have this error message:
   `Unable to register cuDNN factory: Attempting to register factory for plugin cuDNN when one has already been registered`

## reset the TP-Mode.

!pip install tensorflow[and-cuda]

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow import keras
import numpy as np
tf.config.experimental.list_physical_devices()
```

1. for local machine with Jupyter Notebook:
   [PhysicalDevice(name='/physical_device:CPU:0', device_type='CPU'),
   PhysicalDevice(name='/physical_device:GPU:0', device_type='GPU')]
2. For colab and Chrome:
   [PhysicalDevice(name='/physical_device:CPU:0', device_type='CPU')]

Answer (score 0):

maybe you can try 2.13.0, Below is my match, it works

- OS: Centos 7
- cuda: 11.8
- tensorflow[and-cuda]: 2.13.0